# Insert into statement error

Tags: vb.net, insert-into

Try

```
            Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Jen\Documents\Jade\vb\database.accdb")

            txtStatus.Text = "Active"

            Dim account As String = ("Insert into Login(Username, Password, FirstName, LastName, AccountType, Status) VALUES ('" & txtUsername.Text & "' , '" & txtPass.Text & "', '" & txtFirst.Text & "', '" & txtLast.Text & "', '" & cmbType.Text & "', '" & txtStatus.Text & "')'")
            conn.Open()
            ole = New OleDbCommand(account, conn)
            ole.ExecuteNonQuery()

            MsgBox("Successfully Inserted!")

            Dim strsql2 As New OleDbCommand("select * from Login", conn)
            Dim sqlda = New OleDbDataAdapter(strsql2)
            Dim sqldataset = New DataSet
            sqlda.Fill(sqldataset)

            Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = sqldataset.Tables(0)
            conn.Close()
            DataGridView1.Refresh()
```

an error shows that my insert into statement is incorrect. I already check my database many times and retype the code over but still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have Spotted an Extra (') qoute after closing bracket in query.Use this Query and Check

```
 Dim account As String = ("Insert into Login(Username, Password, FirstName, LastName, AccountType, Status) VALUES ('" & txtUsername.Text & "' , '" & txtPass.Text & "', '" & txtFirst.Text & "', '" & txtLast.Text & "', '" & cmbType.Text & "', '" & txtStatus.Text & "')")
```

hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for you help :) i already find the answer :D the word password should be in bracket . I'm using access for database . thnx anway ^^

Answer (score 0):

Are AccountType and Status string type?
if not you should write this:

```
Dim account As String = ("Insert into Login(Username, Password, FirstName, LastName, AccountType, Status) VALUES ('" & txtUsername.Text & "' , '" & txtPass.Text & "', '" & txtFirst.Text & "', '" & txtLast.Text & "', " & cmbType.Text & ", " & txtStatus.Text & ")'")
```